# Armadillo matrix transpose

Tags: c++, matrix, transpose, armadillo

I have a huge m*n matrix A (where the number of rows m is much larger then the number of columns n) which is stored in my c++ program as an `armadillo` `mat` type. Now I have a vector `w` for which I have to calculate `w=w-A*A^T*w` where `A^T` means the transpose of the matrix A.

As the matrix A is very large and consumes a lot of memory, the usual fast approach with armadillo `w=w-A*A.t()*w` does not work, since armadillo consumes a lot of memory in this case (cf. [github](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/203)). The way they resolved this, was by introducing the function `inplace_trans( A, method )`, which can use the method "lowmem" which consumes less memory but needs more time.

My problem is now, that `inplace_trans( A, method )` is a void function, so that I have to create a copy of my matrix first, before I can calculate the new `w`:

```
mat Q = A;
inplace_trans(Q, 'lowmmem');
w=w-A*Q*w;
```

This however is of course not the desired result, since I need a full copy of my matrix, which I wanted to avoid in the first place (RAM problem!).
So, how can I get the transpose of my matrix in an efficient (=fast and low memory demanding) way in order to calculate the new `w`?

If I do it element wise like in

```
mat A(m,n); //huge matrix, initialized before
vec temp(m);
temp.fill(0.0);
for (unsigned long int ii=0; ii<m; ii++){

    for (unsigned long int ll=0; ll<m; ll++){
        temp(ii)+=dot(A.row(ii),A.row(ll))*w(ll);
    }
}
w=w-temp;
```

I have to iterate twice over the number of rows m, which is very costly.

**Edit:**
Up to now the fastest method is the following:

```
vec temp(m);
inplace_trans(A, "lowmem");
temp = A * w;
inplace_trans(A, "lowmem");
temp = A * temp;
```

I have to transpose the matrix twice, because I need it back in its original state afterwards. I cannot believe that this should be the fastest way, since it takes way to much operations, imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly compute `A*A.t()*w` with less work and far less cache misses and only one copy of `A` if you do it element by element.  I don't know what functions armadillo gives you to help make that fast.  But simple access to the rows of the matrix should be good enough to make it practical without using excess memory.

Comment: Maybe I should add that the number of rows m of my Matrix A is much larger than the number of columns n. If I do it element wise, I need two for loops from 0 to m which is far from optimal I guess.

Comment: If the matrix is stored in row major order then element wise is overwhelmingly the faster way compared to transposing first.  If the matrix is stored in column major order, either way is flawed and some other way is better, but what you are simplistically trying to do is still far less efficient than doing it right.

Comment: The matrix is stored in column major ordering. What do you suggest in this case? What do you mean with "doing it right"?

Comment: Can you convert to row major order?  If not, is transposing physical (so a transpose would be in column major order, equivalent to the original in row major order)?  Doing it right clearly involves having only one copy and accessing it in only one sequence.  Probably converting to effectively row major order is worthwhile before accessing.

Comment: The armadillo documentation does not mention the conversion to row major order, unfortunately. From what I get, the transposed matrix is also in column major order.

Comment: If you have any access to the individual columns of the transposed matrix (which would be rows of the original matrix) then each element of `A*A.t()` is just one column of `A.t()` multiplied by another column of `A.t()` and directly doing each of those multiplications would be better than anything separate treatment of `A` and `A.t()`

Comment: Well, your suggestion is exactly what I posted in my question after "If I do it element wise like in...", right? I added this part after your first answer.

Comment: That would have been my suggestion if you hadn't said "column major".  I checked and you are correct about that, so you don't want to access rows that many times.  You want to transpose once and then access columns.

Comment: If I transpose once with `inplace_trans(A, "lowmem");` (which I have to use!) then I have to transpose it back after the multiplication, because I need the original matrix afterwards again. Then I have to do two transpositions, see my original post.

Comment: Alternately, you can construct the sequence of steps that accesses the original matrix in column major order, but computes the same result as `A*A.t()*w`.  That sequence would need to repeatedly access each position of its result, because the source sequence is not appropriate for the destination.  But for cache misses, the source sequence matters enough more that the extra work should not matter.

Comment: May be it would better to place parenthesis: A*(A.t()*w)? In parenthesis we get vector as a result and then again multiply matrix and vector.

Answer (score 1):

In your edit you already correctly imply that it is of course preferable from a complexity point of view, to perform two matrix-vector multiplications, rather than computing `A*A.t()` first an then applying the result to `w`. Your problem however seems to be that you have to transpose the matrix twice.

If you don't need the matrix back in its untransposed form afterwards, a simple solution to that problem is to just transpose the entire equation:
`w = w - A A^T w <==> w^T = w^T - w^T A A^T`. In that case you can first apply `A` and then `A.t()`. If you can somehow define `w` to be a row vector altogether, this would then simply amount to

```
vec temp = w * A;
inplace_trans(A, "lowmem");
temp = temp * A;
w -= temp;
```

Conceptually, there should be no difference in storage between a row and a column vector, the elements should all be contiguous in memory. You would have to take a look at what explicit difference armadillo makes between row and column vectors, but afaik vectors are just matrices with one dimension set to one. Any way, such considerations are much less stringent on the level of vectors than on the level of matrices.